# How to setup MySQL + Tomcat + GWT in Eclipse for Developement mode

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, gwt, tomcat

Is there any way of configuring Eclipse (or GWT?) to run on Tomcat and not on Built-in Jetty server.

I have been playing around with GWT for last few days and have completed the Start-up projects.
Now i want to move to more exciting ones involving database, authentication and multiple modules.

So, the question is How do i configure (or integrate?) Eclipse with GWT, MySQL and Tomcat Server so I can run apps on Tomcat in development mode.

I have come across a few articles but unfortunately they aren't clear enough for me.

Additional Info:

1. Win 7 32 bit
2. Eclipse Helios
3. JDK 1.6 JRE 6
4. Tomcat 6
5. GWT 2.4 (With google plugin for eclipse)
6. MySQL 5.5.20 (Installed as a part of WampServer with PHP and Apache)
7. New-comer to Java, Eclipse, Tomcat and GWT :)

Please guide me how to setup my development environment. Also if you could guide me to some basic tutorial that demonstrate Database communication in GWT, that would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692795/debug-gwt-on-tomcat-using-eclipse/11711185#11711185

Answer (score 1):

Try to test [this](http://boldinventions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95%3ainstalling-apache-and-tomcat-and-mysql-on-window-7&catid=34%3acategory-electronics-articles&Itemid=53&limitstart=5) article. This may be your answer.

Answer (score 0):

first you should read about jdbc to connect the mysql from the eclipse project from which you can easily connect to the mysql(similar to mysql_connect in PHP)