# How run several instances of GWT application in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, configuration

I have two related applications in separate modules, and sometimes I need to launch both.

This cannot be done because of obvious problem - matching ports:

- Jetty http-server occupies `8888` port,
- Server for debug purposes (on which port?).

that will be occupied by first launched application.

And there can be something else that I don't see...

So my question: how to launch several instances of gwt application, in relation to IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port in the VM-properties in the instance of your Jetty-VM for example.

```
-Djetty.port=8100
```

Comment: You can set different port number for code server also. check out this this link for further studies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692795/debug-gwt-on-tomcat-using-eclipse